# Server cannot process .php files - downloads them instead

Tags: php, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I am running IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003 using FastCGI. I have followed the instructions here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php

including this line in my command prompt:

cscript %windir%\system32\inetsrv\fcgiconfig.js -add -section:"PHP" ^
-extension:php -path:"C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe"

However, my server does not recognise .php files. How do I configure my server to send php files to the php-cgi.exe, instead of downloading them?